# How can I ignore SIGXCPU signal, if I want to run a program for a long period of time?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have a C program, executed on Linux, that solves the 'Hanoi_Towers' problem, for n elements, with an iterative solution.

The program works fine up to n = 30, for n = 30 it takes about 3 minutes.

however for a bigger n like for `n = 35`, the program crashes after 10 minutes of runtime.

How can I tell the Linux shell, to let the program run as much as needed to solve the problem?

Comment: How can you be sure that the issue is due to that signal and not to a segmentation fault?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I used the iterative solution, I edited that fact.

Comment: Ok, but if you don't attach the code how can be sure that there are no bugs in youre iterative solution?

Comment: If you are running out of time in some online judge/competition, you are using the wrong algorithm. Many contest/challenge problems are designed so that a naïve algorithm takes a long time but a clever algorithm is quick.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I assume this is the issue, because it works just fine up to n = 30, but you are right, anyway I wanted an answer for the issue in the title, and not specific to my program.

Comment: And what if there's a memory leak that crashes the system after n=32? What if you have an array that goes out of bounds for n=31 cousing segfault?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni how would you suggest, I can be sure what the problem that cause the program to crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore SIGXCPU signal:

```
signal(SIGXCPU, SIG_IGN);
```

This only buys you a little bit more time, though. SIGXCPU starts when you get to the soft CPU limit, and SIGKILL (which you can't ignore) happens once you get to the hard CPU limit.

But you want to check whether the CPU limit is low and if you can increase it. In bash, you can check with `ulimit -t` and change it you could.

Programmatically, you could change `RLIMIT_CPU` via [`setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html).

However, if the CPU limit is set across the system or for specific users by an administrator (e.g. `sysctl` parameters), you'd need super user privileges to change it.